# WebView in android home screen widget

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, widget, remoteview

I want to show **WebView** element inside home screen widget in **Android**. Where I gonna show HTML window from specific web-page. Already tried to make one using **RemoteViews**, but according to docs I can not use all view elements inside RemoteView.

Is any possibility to somehow render HTML page inside home screen widget in android ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to show WebView element inside home screen widget in Android

That is not possible, sorry.

> Is any possibility to somehow render HTML page inside home screen widget in android ?

Not in any practical fashion.